# Exchange - Set "retain deleted Items for" on a mailbox

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

i need to modify the value of *-RetainDeletedItemsFor* of my mailbox but it's always 14, the default value.

I follow the documentation of technet ( https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee364752(v=exchg.150).aspx ) but it doesn't work anyway.

I'm sure that *-SingleItemRecoveryEnabled* is true.

This is my example:

[image]

Any suggestions? thank u

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your mailbox is configured to use the default retention setting for your mailbox database, and this is the value being returned in your `RetainDeletedItemsFor` query.

Run the following command from the shell:

```
Get-Mailbox t.Sync70domain.smtp | fl UseDatabaseRetentionDefaults
```

I think you'll find it returns true, meaning regardess of the value you set for `RetainDeletedItemsFor` your mailbox will use the retention setting for the mailbox database.  And yes, the 14 day setting is the default.

To fix run the following:

```
Set-Mailbox t.Sync70domain.smtp -UseDatabaseRetentionDefaults $false
```